# Fitnesse: test not doing the clean up correctly

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, fitnesse

We are trying to fix some issues on a testing harness, and having issues with a particular test, which basically tests a feature that creates an entity, does some processing and stores it in a database (Yes, the C in CRUD).

In the tearDown section of the fitnesse test, we execute a delete statement on that record. However, nothing is being deleted.

We suspect that this may be because the tearDown is executed before the `SUT` commits its transaction. So consequently, there's nothing to be deleted.

To try and fix this, we are making a pollable jdbc delete:

```
java.sql.Statement statement;
/*creates a statement*/
do{
   recordsDeleted = statement.executeUpdate("delete...");
   Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
}while(recordsDeleted == 0);
```

So here comes the questions:

- When is a jdbc transaction commited?

  In the code above, will the updates be executed on the same transaction, or will a new transaction be created for each iteration of the do-while loop? (I'm inclined to think that they will be executed in the same transaction, since the `java.sql.Connection` holds the `commit`, `rollback`, `etc` methods).
- Can you suggest another solution for this problem? I would think that this is quite common, but my teammates have not found any solution online, just the "poll until its deleted or timeout" suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your loop initially.  You are calling `statement.close()` somewhere right?  I assume the `SUT` is in another thread or is remote?  Are you sure your delete criteria matches the input?  Can you examine the database in another process to see if the create is making it to the database?

In terms of transactions, it depends on the database but typically there are no transactions by default.  Typically auto-commit is enabled so each individual statement is executed and committed immediately.  If you *want* to enable transactions then you need to disable auto-commit and then call `databaseConnection.setSavePoint()`.  A transaction is committed when `commit()` is called.  If the connection is closed (or `rollback()` called) then the transaction is rolled back.